# Error while upgrading PyAudio to latest version

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I have  `PyAudio (0.2.7)` installed in my system.

When I tried to upgrade using

```
sudo pip install pyaudio --upgrade
```

I'm getting this.

```
Downloading/unpacking pyaudio from https://pypi.python.org/packages/44/39/f3b9b16d32cc8588fa06bb2e813cea35363f5502117cd6cc7f619b556d9f/PyAudio-0.2.10.tar.gz#md5=b65354d997fa00a9166f8dbcb83075e6
  Downloading PyAudio-0.2.10.tar.gz (287kB): 287kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pyaudio/setup.py) egg_info for package pyaudio

Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Found existing installation: PyAudio 0.2.7
    Not uninstalling PyAudio at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, owned by OS


                                .......
                                .......

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/_portaudiomodule.o

src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:23: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory

 #include "portaudio.h"

                       ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
  Can't roll back PyAudio; was not uninstalled
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pyaudio/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ih3i9qsm-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pyaudio
Storing debug log for failure in /home/jobin/.pip/pip.log
```

I'm using elementary os 14.04

What is the problem here?

Comment: Don't include images with text, try to include the text itself.

Comment: Have you installed **portaudio-devel**, **libportaudio-dev** or something similar beforehand?

Comment: Nope. I have installed nothing that deals with audio

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm using elementary os 14.04

Answer (score 15):

Thanks @Cristian Ciupitu for the advice to install `portaudio-dev`.

But `portaudio-dev` did not installed with `sudo apt-get install portaudio-dev` in my case.
I got

```
E: Unable to locate package portaudio-dev
```

**How this was solved**

1. Downloaded the **.tgz** of portaudio file from [here](http://www.portaudio.com/download.html)
2. Then Extract the downloaded file.
3. **cd** to the extracted folder.
4. Then **./configure && make**
5. Now do **sudo make install**
6. Then upgrade pyaudio by `sudo pip install pyaudio --upgrade`

Now pyaudio was successfully installed.

Answer (score 3):

run in terminal:

> $ sudo apt install python3-pyaudio

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

> sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev python-pyaudio

then do this

> pip install PyAudio

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the [**portaudio-dev**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libportaudio-dev) package, for example by running:

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio-dev
```

Comment: I'm getting `E: Unable to locate package portaudio-dev
` on running this.

Comment: @jophab, try running `sudo apt-get update` too before that.

Comment: I have tried installing libportaudio-dev. It is now installed. Then I tried upgrading pyaudio. There is some changes in error.

Comment: Not available 
Error
two or more packages specified (libportaudio-dev trusty)

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install pyaudio --upgrade
pip install pyaudio --user
```

Comment: Could you please explain what your solution does and how it solves the problem?